# How do I give a created user access to /dev* in a docker build?

Tags: docker, permissions

I'm attempting to run the command-line version of VLC Player (cvlc) in a bash script within a Docker instance when it starts. VLC Player will not run as root, so a user was created to run it (which works).

Running on a Raspberry Pi 3B+, the attached camera will be accessed via `/dev/video0`. The remaining step is to give the user access to `/dev/video0` so that it can stream video from that source.

Docker.compose

```
version: '2'
services:
  server:
    privileged: true
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
```

Dockerfile.template

```
FROM balenalib/%%BALENA_MACHINE_NAME%%-node

# Install dependencies
RUN install_packages build-essential vlc

RUN useradd -m vlcuser

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# This will copy all files in our root to the working  directory in the container
COPY . ./

# Enable udevd so that plugged dynamic hardware devices show up in our container.
ENV UDEV=1

# server.js will run when container starts up on the device
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/usr/src/app/start.sh"]
```

start.sh

```
su vlcuser -c "cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --v4l2-width 800 --v4l2-height 600 --v4l2-chroma h264 --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=0.0.0.0:8090}' -vvv"
```

The error I'm getting currently:

```
v4l2 stream error: cannot open device '/dev/video0': Permission denied
```

How do I grant permission within the provided Dockerfile.template?

Comment: How about adding the user to the `video` group: `adduser -m -g video vlcuser`? As far as I know the `/dev/videox` directories belong to the group `video` by default.

Comment: Good suggestion. Let me give that a shot now.

Comment: And did it work?

Comment: (confirming, I had modify just a touch)

Comment: While the cvlc command itself needs further work, the permission issue is resolved! @DonFoumare I tweaked yours just a touch: `RUN useradd -m -g video vlcuser`. May I have you add as an answer and I'll pass the points your way? I'll alter my question later with an altered cvlc command for the next person once I figure out what's happening there.

Comment: Nevermind.. i'm glad I could help.

Comment: @DonFoumare Here's a final update. I'll post an answer tomorrow if you don't beat me to it.

I modified my vlc command to something different, `su vlcuser -c "raspivid -o - -t 0 -n -hf -vf -g 25 -pf high -md 4 -fps 25 -b 10000000 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --no-audio --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8090}' :demux=h264"`. Without adding the user to the video group, I was receiving a seemingly unrelated error about invalid input. Adding  the user as part of the video group resulted in a successful stream. Your advise was the missing piece. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: As far as I am aware, I still don't think there is a good, portable, way to create a new user in a docker container and assign them to groups such as dialout, video etc. I opened an issue on vscode's devcontainers extension to solve the problem at least in this context: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7722 (if the issue can get enough up votes then maybe it will be implemented)